# Importing and linking XML in Access 2010

Tags: microsoft-access, xml

I'm trying to link a table in Access 2010 to an XML file and no matter what I do I get this error: "Only XML files can be imported from an Internet address (http://, ftp://). Enter a path that points to a location on your computer or on the network.".

At first I was going to generate the XML on the fly but when the import didn't work I just uploaded a plain XML file (that I exported from Access!) and that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be really nice if Access supported a linked to able to a URI. It certainly knows how to parse, and also it knows how to read a file off the wire (because XML files can be imported via http). But, linking is blocked.

Comment: @PaulKeister Maybe that should be an answer!

Answer (score 3):

HTML and XML import options in Access 2010 are remarkably limited. Here's the gist of it:

- XML: can be read from the local network or via HTTP, but cannot be used to create a linked table.
- HTML: can be used to create a linked table or imported, but can only be read from the local network or file system.

It's very tempting to editorialize about how disappointing this is; in any case those are the facts.